# My friend keeps bugging me to use media prioritization

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

Okay so I online game a lot with my PS3 and WiiU, since I do my friend who games with me says I need to use media prioritization in order to help reduce lag and help with better stability. He told me to put my PS3 as and PlayStation Network in the prioritization.

So I decided to check it out in my router since I'm somewhat knowledgeable when it comes to stuff like this. But I was kinda baffled. I could only put three items in and then there was the downstream bandwidth and such.

I told my other friend about this and he said not to use it since it would make my other devices not work good as well anymore.

So I'm kinda stumped, is there any benefit or disadvantage using it?

Comment: Do you mean QoS (Quality of Service)? QoS is the name for methods of prioritizing various network protocols over a network.

Answer (score 1):

Prioritizing will give your playstation priority over other things that make demands on your network.  In theory it should help with lag IF your bandwidth isn't enough to fulfill all the demands on your network.  If that's the case it will cause other things to lag more when you're using your ps3 (but only when the ps3 is using network connection).

Make sure the connection from your ps3 to your router is good.  If you're running wirelessly, I would try running an Ethernet cable directly from your ps3 to your router before I messed with prioritization.

Another option would be to upgrade you're internet.  Playing games online doesn't require too much bandwidth, 5mb/s download should be sufficient.  If you're hosting games you'll want a decent amount of upload bandwidth as well.  Test your connection using http://www.speedtest.net/.  If you have 10mb/s+ it's probably a problem with the connection between your ps3 and your router (if this is the case, I would run a wire from my router to my ps3).